# API with rails 3.2 and rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rabl

I'm developing an API with rails 3.2 and rabl.

Basically I have a model "Asset", and a very simple associated controller:

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  # GET /assets.json
  def index
    @assets = Asset.all
  end

  # GET /assets/1.json
  def show
    @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /assets/1/edit
  def edit
    @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /assets.json
  def create
    @asset = Asset.new(params[:asset])
    @asset.save
  end
end
```

For each action, I have a associated ACTION.json.rabl view.

For instance, my index.json.rabl is:

```
object @assets
attributes :kind, :description
```

When I issue the following commands, the Asset object is created but with null values:

```
curl -XPOST -d 'kind=house' 'http://localhost:3000/assets.json'
```

Also, where is the mapping between POST/assets.json and "create" function specified ?

Comment: The mapping is specified in the routes.rb when you do `resources :assets`. Can you post your rabl view template?

Comment: @jack-chu thanks, I have updated the question with an example of the rabl file I use. Regarding the mapping, how can I do to map POST/assets.json to a method named "new" for instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal because you do wrong on your curl call. You pass in args only `kind` not `asset[kind]` like you want in your `create` methode with :

```
@asset = Asset.new(params[:asset])
```

Update you curl methode with :

```
curl -XPOST -d 'asset[kind]=house' 'http://localhost:3000/assets.json'
```

Comment: just to understand the access to params[:asset], shouldn't the following command work ?  curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '"asset":{"kind":"flat"}' 'http://localhost:3000/assets.json'. The params[:asset] is left empty.

Comment: I am not a curl expert :( See on your application log to see if the params get are as you want.